# javascript function sharing between all objects in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a function to an array of objects, which each object has access to, but which does not need to be added to each object separately.

Let me give you a short example.

Let's say I have an array containing similar objects, each having a property x and a property y:

```
var objects = [{x:1, y:2},
               {x:0, y:5},
               {x:3, y:14}
              ];
```

I would like to calculate the sum of `x` and `y` for any of the objects.

**First approach:**

In order to calculate the sum for a given object, one could pass this object to a predefined function like so:

```
function xySum1(o) {return o.x + o.y;}

objects[0].x       //--> returns 1
objects[0].y       //--> returns 2
xySum1(objects[0]) //--> returns 3
```

This is quite ugly and unsatisfactory, as accessing the `x` and `y` properties is done differently. Also, my code is in different locations and the function `xySum1` is not easily recognizable as being created to act on the objects in the array.

**Second approach:**

One could loop through the array and add the function as a property to each object:

```
for (var i=0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    objects[i].xySum2 = function() {return this.x + this.y;};
}
```

Now, the sum is obtained by

```
objects[0].x        //--> returns 1
objects[0].y        //--> returns 2
objects[0].xySum2() //--> returns 3
```

which is much better.

*Problems*

There are, however, problems with this approach. Firstly, when I add a new element to the array

```
objects.push({x:5,y:21});
```

then the sum cannot be calculated before the function has been added to the object

```
objects[3].xySum2() //-->TypeError
```

Another problem is that I have many objects, and many functions to add to them. It seems like a waste of good memory space to add each function to each objects individually.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: What about `objects.xySum(0)`?

Comment: maybe define a constructor, then the functions will be in the prototype?

Comment: You can also define a Object.prototype method like this: `Object.prototype.xySum = function() {return typeof this.x !== 'undefined' && typeof this.y !== 'undefined' ? this.x + this.y : undefined;}`.

Comment: @dfsq Extending `Object.prototype` is a **very** bad practice.

Comment: @MaxArt It is bad practice only when you don't know what you do. Extending `Object.prototype` can be quite reasonable approach.

Comment: @Bergi I would like to use it as a property of each object. That way I am still able to use it even if the object is stored in another variable such as `var o = objects[2]` without needing to keep track of the index number.

Comment: @ElRudi: But then you can't work around your first problem - you're having to use a factory function everywhere which amends appended objects. The space won't be a problem, just set all properties to the *same* `function() {return this.x + this.y;}`.

Comment: @dfsq Extenting that means that you have that property `in` *every single object*, which means *everywhere*. Then the keyword `in` then means almost nothing without `hasOwnProperty`. Even if you know what you're doing, it's probably not a good idea, and *definitely* not a good idea to give such advice to a newbie.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define a class:

```
function MyObject(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
MyObject.prototype = {
    xySum2: function() {
        return this.x + this.y;
    }, x: 0, y: 0
};
```

Then you can do:

```
var objects = [
    new MyObject(1, 2),
    new MyObject(0, 5),
    new MyObject(3, 14)
];
objects[0].xySum2(); // 3

objects.push(new MyObject(5, 21));
objects[3].xySum2(); // 26
```

Alternatively, this is what Bergi probably wanted to say in his comment:

```
objects.xySum = function(index) {
    return this[index].x + this[index].y;
};
```

This approach is a little bit "dirtier", but also less memory consuming.

Comment: Thanks MaxArt for your answer. Is there a way to do this once the array of objects has already been created? I ask as it is passed from another part of the program that is beyond my control.

Comment: @ElRudi In that case I suggest to use the alternative: define the function of the `objects` array and you're done. Keep in mind to re-define it in every copy or portion you're going to make of `options`. Or else, you can always create your own array of `MyObject`s using the elements of `objects`, as in `new MyObject(objects[i].x, objects[i].y)`

Comment: So my options: (1) define a class, add wanted function to its prototype -and loop through all the objects in the obtained array to create for each an instance of the class with the same properties, (2)  add the function to the prototype of `Object` instead, which may or may not be terrible coding practice -with the advantage of less lines of code and less looping through arrays, or (3) add the function to the _array_ instead of to the individual objects -with the disadvantage that it is used syntactically different from other properties and is not copied along with object data.
Is about right?

Comment: @ElRudi Essentially, yes. Depending on your needs, choose your solution.